# Website on Amazon EC2 and domain hosted by GoDaddy

Tags: dns, godaddy, migration, amazon-aws, route53

I'm migrating a server over from another cloud provider, to AWS.
My domain name is registered at GoDaddy.com

When moving to AWS, do i need to set up/configure "Route 53" DNS service too somehow, or will everything work when i simply point the "mysite.com" at GoDaddy ,  to my EC2 instance IP shown in amazon control panel ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to get an [Elastic IP Address](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html) and associate it with your EC2 instance. Then you can point your domain to that IP address. You can do this without using Route 53.

Comment: upvoted! so a normal public address that EC2 allocates when you start the instance doesnt work with Godaddy?

Comment: @PirateApp It would, but EC2 instances come and go. If you want to make sure your IP is there for you when you delete your old instance and create a new one, you should get an Elastic IP